# Solve this recursive relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have the following recursive relation ($k$ and $j$ natural numbers):

$$ r_k = r_{k+1} + 2(k+1) $$
And for a specific $j$ 
$$r_j = 0$$

How can I find $r_{k,j}$?

I know the solution, that is:

$$r_{k,j} = j(j+1) - k(k+1)$$

I tried by handling the finite differences, namely:

$$ \frac{\Delta r}{\Delta k} = \frac{r_{k+1} -r_k}{(k+1)-k} = r_{k+1} -r_k =-2(k+1)  $$

And then I integrated $\frac{dr}{dk}$ with the condition $r(j)=0$.

But I did not find the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$\begin{align}r_n&=\sum_{k=j}^{n-1}(r_{k+1}-r_{k})+r_j=\sum_{k=j}^{n-1}(-2(k+1))+0\\
&=-2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(k+1)+2\sum_{k=0}^{j-1}(k+1)
=-2\sum_{k=1}^{n}k+2\sum_{k=1}^{j}k\\
&=-n(n+1)+j(j+1).
\end{align}$$

Comment: Why the downvote?